# Windows 8 Snapped View Caliburn.Micro

Tags: mvvm, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro with my Windows 8 store app. I need to implement a snapped view for each view which normally would be done by making each view a layoutaware page and implementing it that way, however, Caliburn.Micro, at least from what I can tell doesn't allow you to use Layoutaware pages. I haven't been able to find anything regarding how to manage visual state in Caliburn.Micro for WinRT. I have a grid for snapped view that lays out the UI and one for full view, I just need to be able to switch between the two on user command. Any ideas?

Comment: have you seen, http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/403315

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Caliburn.Micro yet, but if it defines its own base page class - you could merge the code from LayoutAwarePage and that base class to have all the support you need.